# Identifying rows in a numpy array that have a given number of matching elements

Tags: numpy

A 2d numpy array has the property that each column holds a distinct range of integers that do not overlap (see b below). An 8, for example, can only appear in the 3rd column.

```
b = [[1, 5, 9, 11, 13],
     [1, 6, 8, 10, 14],
     [2, 4, 8, 12, 15],
     [2, 5, 7, 11, 13],
     [3, 4, 9, 10, 15],
     [3, 5, 7, 12, 14]]
```

I need to know which pairs of rows have EXACTLY 0 matching elements, 1 matching element, ..., 5 matching elements.  In a 'perfect world', the output would look something like the array below.  Rows 0 and 0 have 5 common elements, rows 0 and 1 have 1 common element, etc.

```
out = [[0, 0, 5],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 3],
       ...etc
```

My main problem is how to deal with the 'EXACTLY'.

Comment: Could you eleborate on the expected output? what is out[i, j]; why does out have 3 columns?

Comment: Yes, the first two values in each output row identify the row indexes from array b.   The 3rd value in each output row indicates the number of matched pairs.  So, [0 0, 5] means that when b’s row 0 is compared to row 0, there are 5 pairs of matching values.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Would it also be okay if (given input with N rows), the output was an array of shape N x N, where out[i, j] is the number of common elements between row i and row j?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.  I should mention that the order in which the 2 rows are selected from b doesn’t matter.   So, the index of the 1st row can always be <= the index of the 2nd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of anything better than a list comprehension. You could possibly speed this up by setting `assume_unique=True` if each row does not contain duplicates.

```
import numpy as np

b = [[1, 5, 9, 11, 13],
     [1, 6, 8, 10, 14],
     [2, 4, 8, 12, 15],
     [2, 5, 7, 11, 13],
     [3, 4, 9, 10, 15],
     [3, 5, 7, 12, 14]]

out = np.array([
    [i, j, np.intersect1d(b[i], b[j]).size]
    for i in range(N)
    for j in range(N)
])
```

which should give your expected output, though I find this more intuitive:

```
out = np.array([
    [
        np.intersect1d(rowx, rowy).size
        for rowx in b
    ]
    for rowy in b
])
```

which gives:

```
array([[5, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1],
       [1, 5, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1],
       [3, 0, 1, 5, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 0, 5, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5]])
```

Comment: Thanks.  I added N = 6 to the first solution.

Comment: The first solution gives the desired outcome, but I’m concerned about its speed.   With large arrays, it is very slow.   Is it possible to speed up this process?

Comment: Maybe using numba, but I don't have much experience with that